# Referencing image using GCP-file?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, pyqt, python-3

I'm trying to automate the actual geo-referencing in PyQgis/PyQt5.
I went manually over the built-in GDAL Georeferencer in QGIS and saved a GCP-file. Also, the actual commands used for the conversion are available:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff <gcpString> <inputFile> <tempFile>
gdalwarp -r cubic -order 2 -co COMPRESS=NONE <tempFile> <outputFile>
```

I tried to 'copy' this behaviour in PyQt5 using `subprocess.Popen()` but it seems from PyQgis I do not have permissions or access to the gdal cmd-tools.

Then, I stumbled upon the Python GDAL library which is (I think) built-in with QGIS, and seems a good option. However, I cannot get this to work with the given options as above and documentation is not very easy.
What would be the best approach for referencing the image with a given GCP-file and options?

Comment: Side note: write `<tempfile>` as a virtual file by using `-of VRT`. VRT is a short XML file and much faster to write than the physical GeoTIFF image.

Comment: <tempFile> is just there because the generated script from the referencer-plugin uses one. I actually don't need it, and I'm only interested in the fully referenced and reprojected geoTiff <outputFile>